# Adding domain users to CUPS allow list

Tags: linux, user-accounts, domain, cups

CentOS 6, CUPS. I've been able to log in with my user account to the web admin CUPS login, but I can't work out how to log in with a domain user account (on the command line, it's `domain\user`). Does anyone have a suggestion about how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Add `domain_users` to the SystemGroup in [/etc/cups/cups-files.conf](http://www.cups.org/doc-1.7/ref-cups-files-conf.html):

```
SystemGroup domain_users lpdmin
```

I had an issue that the second group has to enter a password. No idea how to solve this.

Comment: As fr the login, how would I do it via the web interface? domain\user for the username?

Comment: I think you have to allow domain users as described above. Afterwards you should be able to login without passwords. If you try to connect from a remote host you have to allow the host in cupsd.conf (see http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/ref-cupsd-conf.html)

Comment: You can find an short how to set up remote access to cups web interface here: http://thismightbehelpful.blogspot.ch/2008/09/remote-access-to-cups-web-interface.html